# MVC pattern, PHP example?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, open-source

I'd like to know if there is an open source PHP project that is using a MVC pattern that I could learn from its code. Something not too big, and something that could be beneficial for me (a BBS or blog system, for instance) to know how it works on the inside. I'm using the MVC pattern for some of my projects but I never know if I'm doing it right, so basically I just want to see how people are doing it.

If, for example, I study a Bulletin Board System's code, when I'll need a BBS I'll use that one because I'll know how it works on the inside if I ever want to write a mod/add-on or something.

I don't know if it's clear. I think it's a nice way to learn.

Edit: I want to learn how to write my own MVC pattern, to write it from scratch, I don't want to use a framework and I don't want to learn how a framework is written. I want a project that uses its own MVC pattern, no framework.

Comment: Keep in mind, because of the request architecture of the web, the "MVC pattern" in PHP is not "true" MVC.

Comment: @mmmshuddup That makes absolutely no sense at all. Would you care to expand on what you think "true MVC" to be?

Comment: `I'm using the MVC pattern for some of my projects but I never know if I'm doing it right`. You could post your code for review at [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Code Review SE is different from StackOverflow in that code there should be working (whereas StackOverflow is for when it doesn't).

Comment: What I meant by that was that MVC was originally designed for Smalltalk desktop applications in which the view was kept in memory and things like that. "I created the MVC pattern as an obvious solution to the general problem of giving users control over their information as seen from multiple perspectives..  MVC has created a surprising amount of interest." MVC in a GUI is different.. views update themselves. etc. On the web, however, a view can't observe the model (subject->observer doesn't work in it's true form). The list goes on.

Answer (score 4):

[CakePHP](http://cakephp.org), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.org), and [Symfony](http://symfony-project.org/) come to mind.

Take a look at Wikipedia's [comparison of PHP frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP_2) for a detailed breakdown of popular frameworks.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder CodeIgniter has a nice implementation of MVC, but a lot of crappy code otherwise. A very nice and easy framework to use, but a very bad one to learn from.

Comment: @YannisRizos I've perused the CI source before, but never given it a thorough lookover. I figured there was a reason that nickb didn't include it in his list.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder A lot of CI's core was build with PHP4 in mind, so most of what I'm referring to as "crappy code" would more precisely be completely outdated code. I've used it extensively on a project that's nearing 2 million sloc, and I can tell you that although it can perfectly sustain larger projects there are quite a few snafus in its codebase. Take a look at [CI's bug tracker](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues), you'll find quite a few issues regarding CI's poor practices and code (and a lot of them are still open or summarily disregarded).

Comment: @YannisRizos That was one thing I noticed. The CI bootstrap is littered with 'function_exist()`s so that it can provide backwards compatibility for PHP 4. But PHP 4 support is certainly a feature that is less sought after now!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder - Yannis echos my sentiments, which is why I avoid CI when possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's a guy on Youtube called Jesse, he has a channel with a lot's of tutorials, like [MVC](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM) you can learn a lot about how/what/why.

Comment: The first video helped a bit, but it gets messy IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter is a good framework for php which uses MVC.

Answer (score 0):

There's e-commerce open platform called `Magento`.

It utilizes Zend framework.

It is on the bigger side, but you could see how it uses views, controllers and models for various core and custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yii ( http://www.yiiframework.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any built open-source project example, but I can recommend you this **[great article](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/02/building-a-basic-php-e-commerce-application-using-codeigniter-framework-part-1/)**, teaching how to build a E-Commerce App using [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

Even if you don't want to use CodeIgniter, you can learn a lot reading and understanding it.

Answer (score -2):

What comes to mind is looking at a simple framework, I would check out CodeIgniter at http://codeigniter.com/

Often at times it will make your life easier than to understand the more complex frameworks

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

But comes to design patterns, it is really hard to have true MVC with PHP.

- Model - Data
- View - Presentation
- Controller - Business Logic

Often I combine* Model and controller together, and separate the "View" with a templating engine. (such as smarty)

By combine I mean, I have my controller which is the business logic, as well as a separate database class that deals with access the data. And the controller solely uses that db class to work with the data. Thus creating a "semi-true" MVC.

Comment: -1 for `it is really hard to have true MVC with PHP`. There is no such thing as true MVC, if you are referring to the pattern itself it's actually extremely easy to implement in most languages.

Comment: Yes, it is easy to implement in most languages. Some may argue that Controller and view tightly coupled because interaction 
must be interpreted in terms of presentation, while others may argue that Controller and the model are tightly coupled. No software can follow the true "MVC" and all cheats in someway due to architecture  erosion or simply developers being lazy.
http://hci.uwaterloo.ca/courses/cs349/s11/lectures/lecture_10_MVC.pdf

Comment: But that's true for every architectural pattern. Patterns are not supposed to be implemented exactly, they are high level conceptual abstractions. There are bound to be small "cheats" everywhere.

Comment: Which brings back my answer. No software out there (unless if it is a PURELY academic purpose software) will be following the theoretical architectural design. As such my answer states what I do, with the "MVC" approach with PHP, since it is hard to separate the controller and model. But not the view.

Comment: It's not hard to separate the controller and the model, it's actually quite easy. The fact that the controller may contain business logic that uses models, doesn't mean that controller and model are tightly coupled together. Tightly coupled means a controller that's impossible to exist without a model or a view, some implementations REQUIRE you to have a model and a view for each controller. That's what's wrong. If your controller just calls a few models, then you are very close to "true MVC"...